# Tons of "Unknown attribute" errors in AndroidManifest file

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest, attributeerror

After upgrading to API 33 in Android studio, I am getting tons of "Unknown attribute" errors in the AndroidManifest.xml file. I tried invalidating cache and restarting, I tried removing the ~/.gradle/caches/ folder, and still getting the errors. The first two already the versionCode and versionName:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.floritfoto.apps.xvfviewer"
  android:versionCode="147"
  android:versionName="3.10">
  ...
```

Still, the project compiles, and I get no inspection errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update to new version of Android Studio Dolphin. It will fix the error. Dolphin Version is stable now.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases?utm_source=android-studio

Answer (score 2):

API 33 is not supported by Studio Chipmunk: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241460885#comment8

My solution was to upgrade Android Studio to Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 RC 1.